# Remove indent guide lines

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

Netbeans 8 by default shows indent guide lines (light gray dotted vertical lines). How can I turn that feature off?

[image]

Comment: this was annoying me too!

Comment: Particularly annoying for me because I use a proportional (non-monospaced) font, and the lines are incorrectly placed in this situation.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey   is there any particular reason why you use a non-monospaced font? Just wondering.

Comment: @ProfileTwist, Yes. It fits more on the page without the need to scroll. Especially reducing horizontal scrolling. (though in my case I use word wrap, but still it is better to fit more on one line) Reduced scrolling helps me to more quickly read and understand code, especially when I have to glance back up at higher portions of the function that I've already looked past. It is easier for me to read words in variable width, and that is much of my job. Syntax is about the same for me either way.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This can be turned off in menu: View > Show Indent Guide Lines. More about configuring the indent lines in the [release notes](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeans_80_NewAndNoteworthy#Indent_Guide_Lines).

**Release Notes**

> The Guide Lines are dotted lines drawn every tab size before a character on the line. They are shown by default. You can turn off feature in menu View-Show Indent Guide Lines. To change line's color go to Options-Font&Colors-Highlighting-Indent Guide Lines.

Comment: Tip: Instead of removing them, you can change the color and/or opacity to fade them into the BG so they are just very slightly visible, I find them very useful to have - I just don't want them so BOLD!

Answer (score 0):

i went to tools, options, editor, unchecked "use all language settings" then adjusted right margin to 200 and its off the screen, hope it helps